# Perl - Global symbol requires explicit package name

Tags: perl

I am calling a perl subroutine

```
&ProcessInput($line, \%txcountershash, \%txhash);
```

I have this definition:

```
sub ProcessInput() {    
my $word;
my $counterkey;   
my $line = $_[0];
my $countershash = $_[1];
my $outputhash = $_[2];  

# remove all the blanks from the line
$line =~ s/\s+//g;  

my ($port,$counter,$value,$datetime) = split('\|',$line,4);

my $counterdesc = $countershash{$counter};
```

the line that causes the problem is the last line.  It says that global symbol %countershash requires explicit package name.   I'm not sure why it's giving me the error.  There aren't any problems otherwise, if I comment that line out the script runs. The hash is set up as an error code for a key and a description that is the value.  I'm trying to get the value at a particular key in $countershash so I can add the error description to the output hash.

Comment: Also, there is no longer a need to put a `&` at the front of a function call.

Comment: sorry.  clarified.  it is complaining about %countershash.   I realized I'd removed the line that defines $counter by mistake

Comment: Call it as `$countershash->{$counter}`

Comment: Perl is complaining about a hash named `%countershash` which you did not define, instead you have a hashref named `$countershash`.

Comment: ah.  thanks.  that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is dereferencing. you should dereference the hash inside the subroutine

```
my $counterdesc = $countershash->{$counter};
```

`->` this is called [arrow operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator) which is used to deference the array and hashes.

Comment: Please don't show people that horrible syntax. The recommended way to get elements from a hash reference is using `->`. So, `my $counterdesc = $counterhash->{$counter};`.

Comment: @DaveCross Thank you for your comment post edited. :)

Answer (score 0):

The code `$counterhash{$counter}` means "look up the key `$counter` in the hash `%counterhash`". You don't have a hash called `%counterhash`, you have a hash reference in a scalar variable called `$counterhash`. `%counterhash` and `$counterhash` are two completely different variables.

In order to look up an element in a hash reference, you need to use different syntax.

```
my $counterdesc = $countershash->{$counter};
```

Please don't use the `$$countershash{$counter}` syntax (previously) used in another answer. That will only confuse whoever needs to maintain your code in six months time (which might well be you).